# Slim SyntaxError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I decided to try slim template engine, but I have strange error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Unknown line indicator
  app/views/layouts/application.html.slim, Line 1
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
):
  slim (1.1.1) lib/slim/parser.rb:448:in `syntax_error!'
```

It appears on all pages. For example:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-21 09:47:49 +0400
Processing by AuthenticationsController#index as HTML
  Authentication Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "authentications".* FROM "authentications" 
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 17 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 17 LIMIT 1
  Rendered authentications/index.html.slim within layouts/application (88.4ms)
```

I have `gem 'slim-rails'` in my Gemfile and

views/authentications/index.html.slim:

```
table
  tr
    th User
    th Provider
    th Uid
  - for authentication in @authentications
    tr
      td = authentication.user_id
      td = authentication.provider
      td = authentication.uid
      td = link_to "Destroy", authentication, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete
```

views/layouts/application.html.slim:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title gttc
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  body
    p hi!
    = yield
```

I can't figure out cause of this error. It seems like slim parser is trying to parse already generated html. But why? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. When I restarted my IDE (RubyMine) I saw, that on some reason file .html.slim contained text from old .html.erb. So maybe it was just some kind of an error in rubymine.

Comment: Can you explain what you found out a little more? I'm going through the same error and it seems to be intermittent and isolated to my local environment. Thanks!